# How to auto adjust table td width from the content

Tags: html, css, html-table

First please try to look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xe48V/), as you can see I have a table with lots of columns my only problem is how can i make all the `td` adjust its width depending on how long is the text inside of it without wrapping the words?

Here is my code:

```css
.content {
  width: 1100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #fdfdfd;
  margin: 0px auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

.content .content-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#eeeeee), to(#cccccc));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

.content-loader {
  overflow: scroll;
}

.content-loader table {
  width: auto;
  background: #aaa;
}

.content-loader table tr {
  background: #eee;
}

.content-loader table tr td {}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="content-header">

  </div>
  <div class="content-loader">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>First Name</td>
          <td>Last Name</td>
          <td>Gender</td>
          <td>Birth Date</td>
          <td>Address</td>
          <td>Zip Code</td>
          <td>Nationality</td>
          <td>Contact Number</td>
          <td>Email</td>
          <td>Username</td>
          <td>Course</td>
          <td>Year</td>
          <td>ID Number</td>
          <td>Subjects</td>
          <td>Other Fields</td>
          <td>Other Fields</td>
          <td>Other Fields</td>
          <td>Other Fields</td>
          <td>Other Fields</td>
          <td>Other Fields</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can someone please help me with this? Or if it's already been asked here please show me the link.

Comment: remove all widths and add .content-loader table tr td {
    white-space: nowrap;
} ?

Comment: Since you have a fixed width for the container, you have too many fields inside of it to fit properly. If you had less it probably would have adjusted on its own.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Remove all widths set using CSS and set white-space to nowrap like so:

```
.content-loader tr td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I would also remove the fixed width from the container (or add `overflow-x: scroll` to the container) if you want the fields to display in their entirety without it looking odd...

See more here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Answer (score 10):

Use this style attribute for no word wrapping:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

Answer (score 4):

you could also use `display: table` insted of tables. Divs are way more flexible than tables.

Example:

```css
.table {
   display: table;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
 
.table .table-row {
   display: table-row;
}
 
.table .table-cell {
   display: table-cell;
   text-align: left;
   vertical-align: top;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
 <div class="table-row">
  <div class="table-cell">test</div>
  <div class="table-cell">test1123</div>
 </div>
 <div class="table-row">
  <div class="table-cell">test</div>
  <div class="table-cell">test123</div>
 </div>
</div>
```